Prepend and append characters to all string columns in Polars dataframe
For a DataFrame, I want to prepend and append all the strings with extra characters.
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": ["apple", "orange", "grape"],
        "C": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)

To append the strings I can do this
df.with_columns(cs.string() + "||")

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B        ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str      ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ apple||  ┆ a|| │
│ 2   ┆ orange|| ┆ b|| │
│ 3   ┆ grape||  ┆ c|| │
└─────┴──────────┴─────┘

But when I try the same to prepend, I get an error
df.with_columns("||" + cs.string() + "||")


ComputeError: the name 'literal' passed to LazyFrame.with_columns is duplicate
It's possible that multiple expressions are returning the same default column name. If this is the case, try renaming the columns with .alias("new_name") to avoid duplicate column names.


The issue is that, using a literal first defines the name of the output as "literal", which will be duplicated for multiple columns.
You should use name.keep:
df.with_columns(('||' + cs.string() + '||').name.keep())

Output:
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B          ┆ C     │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str        ┆ str   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ ||apple||  ┆ ||a|| │
│ 2   ┆ ||orange|| ┆ ||b|| │
│ 3   ┆ ||grape||  ┆ ||c|| │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘

What happens when '||' is first:
df[['A', 'B']].with_columns('||'+cs.string())

┌─────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ A   ┆ B      ┆ literal  │ <- this gets duplicated when 'C' is present
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ str      │
╞═════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ apple  ┆ ||apple  │
│ 2   ┆ orange ┆ ||orange │
│ 3   ┆ grape  ┆ ||grape  │
└─────┴────────┴──────────┘


While in this case Expr.name.keep is the best solution and does what you want, I'd also like to give a more general solution. You can use expand_selector to resolve a selector to a list of concrete column names, letting you do arbitrary things with them:
df.with_columns([
    ("||" + pl.col(c) + "||").alias(c)
    for c in cs.expand_selector(df, cs.string())
])

expand_selector only operates on the schema (doesn't actually work on data), so it's very fast.

Came up with two solutions

Reverse, append, reverse, append

df.with_columns((cs.string().str.reverse() + "||").str.reverse() + "||")


Regex replace

df.with_columns(cs.string().str.replace("(.*)", "||${1}||"))

The regex replace method is much faster than the reversing method.
Both result in the desired result
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ A   ┆ B          ┆ C     │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str        ┆ str   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ ||apple||  ┆ ||a|| │
│ 2   ┆ ||orange|| ┆ ||b|| │
│ 3   ┆ ||grape||  ┆ ||c|| │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘

